# How can I replace existing blockinfile of a certain marker?

Tags: ansible

I need to replace a specific blockinfile in config with updated information.
Currently, the config looks like this:

```
DATA
DATA
DATA
# <!--BEGIN TO BE UPDATED BLOCK -->
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
# <!--END TO BE UPDATED BLOCK -->
DATA
DATA
DATA
```

and the desired output after running should replace the current`TO BE UPDATED BLOCK`, like this:

```
DATA
DATA
DATA
# <!--BEGIN TO BE UPDATED BLOCK -->
line1
line2
line3
line6
line4
line5
line7
# <!--END TO BE UPDATED BLOCK -->
DATA
DATA
DATA
```

This is what I have but it doesn't seem to do anything to the config file :/

```
-name: replace block
 blockinfile:
 path: "/example.cfg"
 marker: "# <!-- {mark} TO BE UPDATED BLOCK -->"
 block: |
     line1
     line2
     line3
     line6
     line4
     line5
     line7
```

And the run result is giving me
`changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0`

Any ideas?

Comment: could you confirm the indentation of the task? `path`, `marker` and `block` should be set as a child of `blockinfile`

Comment: also, the path indicates that the expected file path will be set in the root directory, was this file created? if the task was executed several times, that will report the `changed` as zero

Comment: The marker you are showing in the file is `#<!--BEGIN TO BE UPDATED BLOCK>` and your tentative shows `marker: "# <!-- {mark} TO BE UPDATED BLOCK -->"`, those are two totally different markers. Have you tried `marker: "#<!--{mark} TO BE UPDATED BLOCK>"` ?

Comment: Sry @β.εηοιτ.βε it was a typo, the markers there are the same. In fact that ansible task was the one that originally created the config file block, now with different info

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue and there was an extra space in marker argument. I run the below and the changes performed succesfully:

```
---
- hosts: nodes
  tasks:
    - name: replace block
      blockinfile:
        path: "/example.cfg"
        marker: "# <!--{mark} TO BE UPDATED BLOCK -->"
        block: |
            line1
            line2
            line3
            line6
            line4
            line5
            line7
```